# What is the name of a pick-up-sticks or jackstraws pile?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a specific name (a single word or phrase) for the pile, heap, nest, clump, cluster, configuration, stack or arrangement of sticks or shapes used in [pick-up-sticks](http://www.ehow.com/how_2105655_play-jack-straws.html) or [jackstraws](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-the-game-of-jackstraws.htm), when piled up for play?  If so, what is the word or phrase?

Note, in [pick-up-sticks](http://www.boowakwala.com/stick/pick-up-stickgame.html) straight sticks of various colors are used; in jackstraws, many of the objects of the game are molded or [carved shapes](http://www.mainememory.net/artifact/6882/enlarge).   Also note, the game is sometimes called *spillikins*, and a *[spillikin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spillikin#English)* is  “One of the straws used in the game of jackstraws (spillikins)”.

Comment: What's wrong with `heap` or `pile`?

Comment: If someone says *heap* or *pile*, do you automatically think of a nest of pick-up-sticks?  Neither word is specific to the case.  Is there a word that is?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you wanted a word that *only* referred to a pile of pick-up-sticks.

Comment: The official Parker Brothers rules for jackstraws (found [here](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/JackStraws,thegamefo-inenglishandspanish.PDF) in several different versions) call it a *pile* or a *heap*. In French, they call it *un tas*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jumble* seems to be a word that's associated with both [pick-up-sticks](http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/ABOUT-WORDS/2001-09/0999818579) and [jackstraw](http://www.yourdictionary.com/jackstraw).

It's amusing to Google "jackstraws jumble" and note all the instances where *jackstraws* and *jumble* are used in association ([“The jackstraw jumble of rotting wood made for uncertain footing.”](http://www.wordnik.com/words/jackstraw)), probably because of the alliteration involved.